# Create multiple clones of site with different branding?

Tags: multisite

I would like to be able to have multiple clones of a website where the branding/logos are different, but all the other content is the same.

Ideally, these would be subdomains.

```
company1.mywebsite.com
company2.mywebsite.com
```

I've been looking into Multisite but I'm not sure that's right for this.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: multisite would be better for this.

Comment: @ChetanVaghela Multisite is the opposite of what they want. Multisite makes it easy to share a design and users between sites, but the content is separate. They want the same content with different branding.

Comment: Separate installs that you push the same codebase to in one go would probably be best. As long as you have a child theme set up in each that covers the logos/branding, you can then update themes and plugins all at once. You might want to look into hosts with staging or cloning capabilities - if you can clone one site's content directly to another, that would make maintaining the content easier. However, just so you are aware, having all this duplicate content will mean that search engines will tend not to rank all the separate sites, which may or may not matter to you.